# Regarding subgroups of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ of order $p$, where $p$ is an odd prime dividing $q+1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The problem (this is not a homework problem, though it does feel like one):

Suppose *p* and *q* are primes such that $p \vert q+1$ and *p* is odd. Then all subgroups of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{q})$ of order *p* are conjugate to one another.

What I know so far:

First of all, $\vert GL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{q})\vert = q(q+1)(q-1)^2$.

If $q=2$, then $p=3$ and  $\vert GL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{q})\vert =6$. Then the only subgroup of order $p$ is the unique Sylow $3$-subgroup. Of course this subgroup is conjugate to itself.

So, now we look at the case where $q$ is an odd prime. Obviously $p \nmid q(q-1)^2$. But, $p$ may not be the largest power of $p$ dividing $q+1$. So, the subgroups of order $p$ are not necessarily Sylow $p$-subgroups. Of course, they must be conjugate to a subgroup of a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

What is the right way to complete this argument? I am hoping for an answer that pushes me in the right direction without giving it all away (at least for now).

Thanks for your time. My apologies for the very basic question.

Edit: Check the comments below Derek's hint for a solution. Please let me know if you spot any problems with my argument.

Comment: Order-$p$ subgroups are in 1-to-1 correspondence with order-$p$ elements (since $p$ is a prime). Note that "conjugate" on the level of subgroups corresponds not to "conjugate" on the level of elements, but "conjugate to a nontrivial power" on the level of elements, under this correspondence. Order $p$ in characteristic $q$ behaves "more or less" like in characteristic $0$ since $q\equiv -1\not\equiv 0\mod p$. In particular, any element of $GL_2\left(\mathbb{F}_q\right)$ of order $p$ is a matrix diagonalizable over a field extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$. Its two eigenvalues ...

Comment: ... must be powers of the primitive $p$-th root of unity. The product of this powers is the determinant of this matrix, and thus lies in $\mathbb{F}_q$, but it is also a $p$-th root of unity, and hence $1$ (since the only $p$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{F}_q$ is $1$). Thus, any element of $GL_2\left(\mathbb{F}_q\right)$ of order $p$ is similar to a matrix of the form $\mathrm{diag}\left(\zeta^i,\zeta^i\right)$ over a field extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $\zeta$ is a fixed primitive $p$-th root of unity, and $i\in\left\lbrace 1,2,...,p-1\right\rbrace$. In particular, any such ...

Comment: ... matrix is similar to some power of any other such matrix. Now, recall that if two matrices over a field $F$ are conjugate over some extension field, then they are already conjugate over $F$.

Comment: If the above is correct, then instead of $p\mid q+1$ we only used $p\nmid q$ and $q\not\equiv 1\mod p$.

Comment: Pretty much everything I wrote in my above comments is slightly wrong (e.g., there is no "1-to-1 correspondence", and "$\operatorname{diag}\left(\zeta^i, \zeta^i\right)$" should be "$\operatorname{diag}\left(\zeta^i, \zeta^{-i}\right)$"), but the idea is right: Every order-$p$ element of $\operatorname{GL}_2\left(\mathbb{F}_q\right)$ must be similar (over $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$) to $\operatorname{diag}\left(\zeta^i, \zeta^{-i}\right)$ for some $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\right\}$, because its two eigenvalues must be $q$-th roots of unity whose product is in $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sylow $p$-subgroups of ${\rm GL}_2(q)$ (for $p$ an odd prime dividing $q+1$) are cyclic. Using that fact, you should be able to prove using Sylow's Theorem that all subgroups of order $p$ are conjugate.

To see that the Sylow $p$-subgroups are cyclic, observe that ${\rm GL}_2(q)$ contains an element of order $q^2-1$ arising from multiplication by a multiplicative generator of the field ${\mathbb F}_{q^2}$ of order $q^2$.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I will accept your answer as soon as I get a chance to work out the details tomorrow afternoon.

Comment: I see now that the linear map multiplication by a generator for $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}^{\times}$ gives rise to an element $A$ of order $q^2-1$ of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ by choice of a basis for $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ as an $\mathbb{F}_q$-vector space. If we factor $q+1=kp^\alpha$, where $p\nmid k$, then the element $A^{k(q-1)}$ has order $p^{\alpha}$, and so generates a cylic Sylow $p$-subgroup. Since the Sylow $p$-subgroups are all isomorphic, this means that the Sylow $p$-subgroups are all cylic.

Comment: Now if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are two subgroups of order $p$ and $P$ is a Sylow p-subgroup, then by the Sylow theorems, there are elements $g, h \in GL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ such that $g^{-1}H_{1}g \leq P$ and $h^{-1}H_{2}h \leq P$. But since there is a unique subgroup of order $p$ in $P$, we have $g^{-1}H_1g=h^{-1}H_2h$. Thus, $H_1$ and $H_2$ are conjugate by the element $gh^{-1}$.  Are there any problems with the way I argued this?